# Is it possible to create keycloak users without admin credentials?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have a spring boot application which use keycloak for user management. But the keycloak instance is a production one and I don't have admin credentials. I following keycloak realm information.

```
#Keycloak settings
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://myapp.com/auth/
keycloak.realm=project-realm
keycloak.resource=project-client
keycloak.credentials.secret=secret
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.ssl-required=external
auth.token.url=https://myapp.com/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
auth.grant.type=client_credentials
```

When I try do perform user management operations using keycloak rest api I get **403 Forbidden** response. Here the authorization token is generated using above **realm credentials**.

```
method: POST 
url:https://myapp.com/auth/realms/project-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
body:
client_id: project-client
grant_type: client_credentials
client_secret: secret
```

But when I use a local keycloak instance and generate authorization token using **admin credentials** this works fine.

```
method: POST 
url:http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
body:
client_id: admin-cli
grant_type: password
username: admin
password: admin
```

What I need to know is do I need admin credentials (username, password) to perform these user management operation using Keycloak rest api? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I try do perform user management operations using keycloak rest
> api I get 403 Forbidden response. Here the authorization token is
> generated using above realm credentials.

This happens because

```
method: POST 
url:https://myapp.com/auth/realms/project-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
body:
client_id: project-client
grant_type: client_credentials
client_secret: secret
```

your client `project-client` does not have the proper admin-related roles to perform the Admin Rest API calls.

> What I need to know is do I need admin credentials (username,
> password) to perform these user management operation using keyclaok
> rest api? Or am I doing something wrong?

No. You can perform those same tasks with another user or client as long as they have the appropriate roles. To fix your problem you can do the following:

- Go to the realm where the client `project-client` is;
- Go to Clients and select the client `project-client`;
- Switch to the tab `Service Account Roles`;
- In the `Client Roles` dropdown menu select `realm-management`;
- Select and assign the roles accordingly:

[image]